# Does the defendant give his testimony in Nefoshos trials?

Tags: beit-din-court, maseches-sanhedrin, criminal-procedure

The Gemmorah dedicates pages for discussing interrogation of witnesses in Nefoshos trials (NOT MAMONOS, NOT ISHUS), but I don't recall a discussion about the testimony of the defendant. Although the Mishna (Sanh 5,4) says:

> "ואפילו הוא אומר **יש לי ללמד על עצמי** זכות, שומעין לו, ובלבד שיש ממש בדבריו"

I couldn't find the details of the defendant's interrogation.

So how did it go?

Comment: What need is there to interrogate him?

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you serious? Place yourself in his shoes.

Comment: In the USA defendants aren't interrogated in court, so in my shoes my comment above seems quite natural. That right is guaranteed to all Americans by the Fifth Amendment